# Split list with map

Tags: ocaml

How can I replicate the function of the List module: "List.split", with map?

I've found a way to do it with fold_right, but I don't quite understand how to do it with map...

```
let split l =
List.fold_right(fun (x, y) (xs, ys) -> (x :: xs, y :: ys)) l ([], []);;
```

Comment: What makes you think you _can_? `map` will return a list of equal length to the input with the elements transformed according to the given function.

Comment: @glennsl Should I use "List.map2" then? I'm still learning Ocaml so I'm pretty lost ... but I understand that I should apply the function to each tuple ... right?

Comment: `List.map2` has the same problem explained by @glennsl. It always returns a list of the same length as the *two* lists you give it. Your function is supposed to return a pair of lists. The most general list processing functions are the folds: `List.fold_left` and `List.fold_right`. As you discovered, they will work for you. You can also write your own recursive function, but using a fold gives better code (more comprehensible by experienced coders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be something as simple as:

```
let split l =
  (List.map (fun (a, _) -> a) l,
   List.map (fun (_, b) -> b) l)
```

Comment: Suggested: `let split l = (List.map fst l, List.map snd l)`